# Unsure on how to fix PTR

Tags: gmail, reverse-dns, google, linode, ptr-record

I am trying to setup a custom email for a company website. The only issue is that when sending an email to a gmail account, I get the following back:

```
The mail system : host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com said:
The IP address sending this message does not have a PTR record setup, or the corresponding forward DNS entry does not point to the sending IP. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#ip-practices for more information.
```

I have my records on Cloudflare as seen here:
[Image of DNS records on Cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S23Qa.png)

On Linode which is hosting my VPS, I have the rDNS as seen here:
[Image of rDNS on Linode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0baiG.png)

I used an email checker `mail-tester.com` to check my email `noreply@example.com`. It returned the following: [Image of mail-tester output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xkaw.png)
I don't quite understand what the issue is as I have never done this before.

Comment: Your PTR and HELO mismatch. Just fix your HELO or point the PRT accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your email server is sending example.com in the HELO command rather than mail.example.com. You need to change this in the configuration of your email software.

Comment: I didn't setup the software. I ran this script: https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/emailwiz
So I don't really know how I would go about editing that.

Comment: The forward and reverse record must match. E.g. `mail.example.com` *must* point to your ip, and the PTR for your IP *must* point to `mail.example.com`